# getting the fold state of lines in nested folds

Tags: vimscript, folding

vim provides the methods [foldclosed()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#foldclosed%28%29) and [foldclosedend()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#foldclosedend%28%29) to get the first and last line of a closed fold.
The problem is: It does not respect nested folds.

For example this file:

```
line 1
  line 2
  line 3
    line 4
    line 5
  line 6
line 7
```

has manual folds:

1. line 1 - 6
2. line 3 - 5

All of them are closed (first the second, inner, fold, then the first, outer, fold).
When calling `foldclosed(4)` and `foldclosedend(4)` I would expect to get the values `3` and `5`, since this is the fold line 4 is contained in. However it returns `1` and `6` for all lines except 7 (which is not in a fold).

Is there a way to get the fold state of each fold that respects nested folds? I expect something like what [mkview](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#%3Amkview) does, which remembers the correct nested folds:

```
3,5fold
1,6fold
1
normal! zo
3
normal! zc
1
normal! zc
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no builtin vim-script function which provides that. But you can make your own using builtin [`foldclosed`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#foldclosed%28%29) [`foldclosedend`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#foldclosedend%28%29) and [`foldlevel`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#foldlevel%28%29) functions.
Here is a snippet I made:

```
function NestFoldClosed(lnum)
  let b = foldlevel(a:lnum)
  let lnum = a:lnum
  if b > 1 
    let temp = b
    " find the previous line that has foldlevel one less than the current line
    while(temp == b)
      let lnum = lnum - 1
      let temp = foldlevel(lnum)
    endwhile
    return lnum + 1
  endif
  return foldclosed(a:lnum)
endfunction

function NestFoldClosedEnd(lnum)
  let b = foldlevel(a:lnum)
  let lnum = a:lnum
  if b > 1 
    let temp = b
    " find the next line that has foldlevel one less than the current line
    while(temp == b)
      let lnum = lnum + 1
      let temp = foldlevel(lnum)
    endwhile
    return lnum - 1
  endif
  return foldclosed(a:lnum)
endfunction
```

Now if you do the following and call `NestFoldClosed(4)` and `NestFoldClosedEnd(4)` you will get the correct line numbers.

```
:3,5fold 
:1,6fold 
:1 
:normal! zo 
:3 
:normal! zc 
:1 
:normal! zc
```

Comment: Wow, that works very vell! Many thanks!

Comment: There is a simple mistate in the code that the `#` is used as comment character instead of `"`, but stackexchange won't let me edit that since it is less than 6 characters to be changed…

Comment: Hmm, apart from the first impression, it does not fully work, unfortunately. If all folds (in this example) are closed, it returns the correct values. If only the outer one is closed, it still returns the same values. Even worse, if all folds are open it still returns `3` and `5` for the inner fold.

Comment: @radlan after replacing `#` with `"` syntax highlighting does not work properly so I am keeping `#` instead for readability.

Comment: @Coder_H StackExchange (unfortunately) does not have vimscript highlighting yet, but we would still prefer the correct code.